# Why Do I Get "Unhandled exception: Not a string or buffer Type"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The error originates from the line below, which does not make sense because I'm following the example correctly (https://www.npmjs.org/package/aws-sign). Any hint is appreciated.

```
var signer = new AwsSign({
        accessKeyId: 'AKIAIO7EXAMPLE',
        secretAccessKey: 'bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY',
});
```

Error

```
 Caught unhandled exception:  Not a string or buffer TypeError: Not a string or buffer
    at exports.createHmac (crypto.js:138:21)
    at hmacSha1 (/rhel5pdi/workplace/jamiey/jamiey-awsProject/src/awsProject/node_modules/aws-sign/index.js:62:17)
    at sign (/rhel5pdi/workplace/jamiey/jamiey-awsProject/src/awsProject/node_modules/aws-sign/index.js:77:10)
    at new authorization (/rhel5pdi/workplace/jamiey/jamiey-awsProject/src/awsProject/node_modules/aws-sign/index.js:47:39)
```

Comment: @JacobMattison - The last comma in an Object literal is acceptable.

Comment: This exception is coming from deep down in the `AwsSign` implementation.  If it were me, I'd set a breakpoint at the source of the exception and examine the local state on the line before the exception occurs to see what variable it is not happy about and see what I learn from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with string buffer. It's caused by not having the module installed correctly. Double check to make sure the module is installed.